# How to add Title and Subtitle in android RadioButton?

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I want to know how to add subtitle in RadioButton in android.
Like in the image below.

**Radio Button with Subtitle**
[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: That might be a `RadioButton` with no text, with two `TextView` widgets adjacent to it. Alternatively, you could try using spans and a newline in the `RadioButton` text to handle the formatting. Use the Layout Inspector in Android Studio to see what that particular dialog is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RadioButton` without text. And for text use `TextView`. Check

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="Phone Storage"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="/storage/emulated/0/Xender"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done by using A **RadioButton** with two **TextView** as mentioned by CommonsWare but there aren't any built-in widget for this.

here how is how you can achieve this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rbSwitch"
        android:text="Phone Storage"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rbSwitch"
        android:text="/storage/emulated/0/Xender" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: This works for me UI wise but I cannot add this RadioButton to the same RadioGroup as other Radiobuttons