# How to add a subtext message to a RadioButton that is located inside a RadioGroup in Android?

Tags: android

As the title suggests, I'm trying to add subtext to a series of RadioButtons located inside a RadioGroup, but there is no such attribute that allows you to add a subtext like `android:text""`, I have also tried a different way of doing it, by not using any text attribute, and instead using 2 different TextViews, so 1 RadioButton and 2 TextViews inside a RelativeLayout, and various of those inside a RadioGroup, but the problem with that is that it allows me to check as many RadioButtons I want, not being able to uncheck them afterwards.

Here is my code (java is irrelevant here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightblack"
    tools:context=".ActivityLevel">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_activity_level">
    </include>

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/buttonLow"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonLowText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Low"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textGray"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Little or no exercise"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonLowText"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/buttonModerate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonModerateText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Moderate"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textGray"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Light exercise, sport 1-3 times per week"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonModerateText"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/buttonHigh"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonHighText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="High"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textGray"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Moderate exercise, sport 3-5 times per week"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonHighText"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/buttonVeryHigh"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonVeryHighText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Very high"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textGray"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Intense exercise, sport 6-7 times per week"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonVeryHighText"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/buttonHyperactive"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/buttonHyperactiveText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Hyperactive"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textGray"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Very intense exercise, professional athlete"
                    android:layout_below="@id/buttonHyperactiveText"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    />


            </RelativeLayout>

        </RadioGroup>

    </RelativeLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59696021/how-to-add-title-and-subtitle-in-android-radiobutton

Comment: @Rus_o Hey, I have looked at this question and its respective answers before, but it doesn't help me much, because it points towards what I already have.